# How to treat a magnolia with white fuzz on its leaves?

Tags: plant-health, diseases, leaves, plant-care, magnolia

I can’t find photos with similar problem in the internet. Therefore, I don’t know how to treat this. Please help me, the tree looks worse each day.

[image]

Comment: looks a lot like mealybug to me.  If you can wipe it off then likely it is an insect,  how big is the tree?  where in the world is it?

Comment: @kevinsky oh, maybe you are right. I thought that it is mold\mildew and searched it. I am from Texas, USA. We bought this tree approximately 7 months ago. Thank you very much!

Comment: Send a better picture or two...this looks like leaf miner.  How did you plant this tree?  Sun or partial shade?  Fertilizer?  Looks healthy except for the white vining stuff.  Not powdery mildew...Leaf miners lay eggs under the epidermis.  The babies eat the leaf before they mature and fly away.  Need to know where you live and where you planted and how you planted this tree.  Catch problems early easy to correct.

Comment: @stormy Thank you for an answer. It is pretty sunny weather, I live in Texas, USA. No Fertilizer, only added a thing to make the ground more acidic. I am almost sure this is mealybug because I found few fuzzy white bugs with wings and several larvae.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is pretty hard to treat. In my experience you can combat this by spraying the plant with neem oil. Remove the leaves with the fuss and dispose of them in a plastic bag so they do not contaminate any other plants. Spray the tree once a week with the neem oil. Any leaves that are dead or yellowing prune off the tree. Then to strengthen the tree fertilize it to give it a fighting chance.

Comment: Wait, do not remove the leaves with the fuzz.  Just spray with neem.  Make sure you read the entire information packet a couple of times, okay?  Neem is all you need.  Remove dead leaves sure but do not remove any leaves with fuzz.  This is a normal little insect and not a pandemic.  Your tree needs all the photosynthesizing factories possible to make food for itself.  Fertilizer is a basic, it is not to be used for medicine.  If you've not fertilized time to consider doing so...Tree stakes work well.  Balanced NPK.  Spray your tree at night ONCE.  Check in a few weeks if a second spray needed

Comment: This is not hard to treat at all.  Spray at night not during the day, please.  For the bees!  Even if the info on the neem says safe for bees don't spray during the day.  A bee gets chemistry on its legs it takes it back to harm the entire hive.  Spray at night, UNDER the leaves and the trunk, stems branches, cover your eyes, face and arms if possible, take a bath right after.  Otherwise an effective, fairly safe pesticide...oh so Organic.

Comment: The reason why this is hard to treat is it spreads fast and easily meaning you have to constantly look after it. This is a pain if you own a greenhouse because instead of selling plants you are losing profits containing this pest. It is best to treat all bugs, fungi and diseases with respect and do remove the leaves that are infected this triggers the plant to produce more leaves and fuller branches which in return combats the disease this is a technique that can be read about in most gardening books. Other than that I agree with stormy